# Why might a "yum upgrade" appear to work but not actually apply anything?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I have a server running CentOS (with Fasthosts UK).

Running a "yum upgrade" lists - and processes - a LOT of packages that it has upgrades for. Everything is downloaded and installed.

The problem is that if I do a subsequent "yum upgrade", it list all the same upgrades again! As if it was only running as a simulation and didn't really apply any upgrades.

This effectively means that I can't upgrade any of the software packages on my server ("yum upgrade specificpackage" also has the same problem) and so I wondered if anybody has any kind of experience or advice about this?

Is this a CentOS issue or a Fasthosts issue?

PS. FWIW there is also Plesk intalled on this server.

Comment: So you are running 

   yum upgrade

And then Typing 'y' for yes, and hitting enter?

Comment: As I recall (have to admit I haven't done this v. recently) - yes

Comment: (348/348): java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.11.b16.el5.x86_64.rpm                   |  35 MB     00:04     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                  2.0 MB/s | 360 MB     02:55     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/spfquery from install of perl-Mail-SPF-2.006-1.el5.rf.noarch conflicts with file from package spf2-1.2.5-0.274900.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------

Comment: Above dump is poorly formatted, but a transaction test runs for a few mins (after all the downloads) then reports one transaction check error. no errors are listed in the error summary. But then doing a "yum upgrade" lists all the same package candidates again :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that log snippet, it looks like you may have some repository priority conflicts.  In my experience, the various repositories for CentOS are not well-coordinated.  RPMForge doesn't always play nicely with EPEL, for example, and you get version number races.

To get more information, you could make yum run in verbose mode with the -d (debug) and -e (error level) switches.  NUM should be between 1 and 10.

You might also try using --skip-broken, which should only hold back the package that's causing problems.

Comment: Some v. useful info - thanks, I'll investigate. I have indeed added the RPMForge repo.

Comment: --skip-broken sounds great and I was actually imagining using something like that - will try - thanks

Comment: upboat - the problem is that yum is bailing out on you due to an error, so the right thing is actually happening. --skip-broken is your friend if you don't want to debug further, eventually it will get fixed upstream and work later (usually :) ).

Comment: yum upgrade --disablerepo=rpmforge seems to be churning away now!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this specifically, but the first thing I would try is `yum clean all` to clean up package data, caches and the rpm database.  Then see if you get the same results after another update.

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you say there is a "transaction check error". This is likely the problem. You should paste that here, although depending on what the problem was, it may have solved itself by now.

As other posters pointed out, some of the third party repos. are not very well managed. At most I would recommend: RHEL, EPEL, rpmfusion* and iuscommunity.